# Render component when props changed, otherwise not shown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this Output component which should be rendered when it get props from the parent component.

How can I do this?
Right now, it renders when I click a button but without the getTranslate function getting called. In debugger I can see that the component has the props needed, it just doesn't run my getTranslate function

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import Axios from "axios";

const Output = (props) => {
  const [output, setOutput] = useState(null);
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(null);

  const getUrl = (language, text) => {
    console.log("GetURL ran with: ", language, text);
    let url = "";
    switch (language) {
      case "yoda":
        url =
          " https://api.funtranslations.com/translate/yoda.json?text=" + text;
        break;

      case "valyrian":
        url =
          "https://api.funtranslations.com/translate/valyrian.json?text=" +
          text;
        break;

      case "sith":
        url =
          "https://api.funtranslations.com/translate/sith.json?text=" + text;
        break;

      case "shakespeare":
        url =
          "https://api.funtranslations.com/translate/shakespeare.json?text=" +
          text;
        break;

      case "pirate":
        url =
          "https://api.funtranslations.com/translate/pirate.json?text=" + text;
        break;

      case "minion":
        url =
          "https://api.funtranslations.com/translate/minion.json?text=" + text;
        break;

      case "lolcat":
        url =
          "https://api.funtranslations.com/translate/lolcat.json?text=" + text;
        break;

      case "klingon":
        url =
          "https://api.funtranslations.com/translate/klingon.json?text=" + text;
        break;

      case "hacker":
        url =
          "https://api.funtranslations.com/translate/hacker.json?text=" + text;
        break;

      case "dothraki":
        url =
          "https://api.funtranslations.com/translate/dothraki.json?text=" +
          text;
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }

    setUrl(url);
  };

  const getTranslate = () => {
    getUrl(props.language, props.text);
    const axios = require("axios");
    axios.get(function (respone) {
      console.log("Here comes response from api call: ", respone);
      return respone.contents.translated;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <textarea placeholder="Translated..." value={{ getTranslate }}></textarea>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Output;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probable problem is you are not calling getTranslate function, looks like it should be getTranslate(); also you need to update state once you receive data.. see I have placed comments to guide to towards a solution... getTranslate  is not returning any value, and the place you are calling it not appropriate...

```
const getTranslate = () => {
    getUrl(props.language, props.text);
    const axios = require("axios");
    axios.get(function (respone) {
      console.log("Here comes response from api call: ", respone);
/// update the variable /state/ prop that you want to bind
      return respone.contents.translated;
    });
  };
```

Then bind the value in template:

```
return (
    <div>
      <textarea placeholder="Translated..." value={ the value to bind from state/prop}></textarea>
    </div>
  )
```

;

Answer (score 0):

To call getTranslate(), you can use hooks lifecycle method useEffect(). And value returned from this function can be set to some state and bind the set state to text area value.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import Axios from "axios";

const Output = (props) => {
  const [output, setOutput] = useState('');
  const [url, setUrl] = useState('');

  useEffect(()=>{
    getTranslate();

  })

  const getUrl = (language, text) => {
    console.log("GetURL ran with: ", language, text);
    let url = "";
    switch (language) {
      case "yoda":
        url =
          " https://api.funtranslations.com/translate/yoda.json?text=" + text;
        break;

      case "valyrian":
        url =
          "https://api.funtranslations.com/translate/valyrian.json?text=" +
          text;
        break;

      case "sith":
        url =
          "https://api.funtranslations.com/translate/sith.json?text=" + text;
        break;

      case "shakespeare":
        url =
          "https://api.funtranslations.com/translate/shakespeare.json?text=" +
          text;
        break;

      case "pirate":
        url =
          "https://api.funtranslations.com/translate/pirate.json?text=" + text;
        break;

      case "minion":
        url =
          "https://api.funtranslations.com/translate/minion.json?text=" + text;
        break;

      case "lolcat":
        url =
          "https://api.funtranslations.com/translate/lolcat.json?text=" + text;
        break;

      case "klingon":
        url =
          "https://api.funtranslations.com/translate/klingon.json?text=" + text;
        break;

      case "hacker":
        url =
          "https://api.funtranslations.com/translate/hacker.json?text=" + text;
        break;

      case "dothraki":
        url =
          "https://api.funtranslations.com/translate/dothraki.json?text=" +
          text;
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }

    setUrl(url);
  };

  const getTranslate = () => {
    console.log("From get translate")
    getUrl(props.language, props.text);
    Axios.get(function (respone) {
      console.log("Here comes response from api call: ", respone);
     setOutput(respone.contents.translated);
    });

  };

  return (
    <div>
      <textarea placeholder="Translated..." value={output} onChange={()=>console.log("Testing")}></textarea>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Output;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your translate functionality to either the "onChange" function or the "onBlur" function (if you want the text to be translated after the user clicks out).
Also the functions you pass to onChange and onBlur should manage the async nature of your translate functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a useEffect Method which will run every time when props changes or component renders.

```
useEffect(()=>{
getTranslate();

 }, [props])
```